# iOS how to get the exact font and size of the keyboard shown for a text field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uifont

I'm interested in getting the exact font size and name of a keyboard currently displayed on a screen, as a first responder for a UITextField. I see that iPhone6 and iPhone 5 use different font size, and I think custom keyboards can be using an even more diverse set of fonts.

**How can I extract the font in which the letters on the iphone keyboard are drawn?**

[image]

Comment: Do you want this information in runtime or so you can set your constants to these sizes for each device type?

Comment: I would like to have it at runtime so I can set the font of a text field to the same one